# Unexpected outcome with Elasticsearch-DSL filter

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm new to Elasticsearch and python's `elasticsearch-dsl` and I really can't figure out why my filter returns no results:

```
In [1]: from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch 
   ...: from elasticsearch_dsl import Search 
   ...:  
   ...: search = Search(using=Elasticsearch())                                            

In [2]: search.execute()                                                     
Out[2]: <Response: [<Hit(general-index/1): {'first_name': 'Piero', 'full_name': 'Piero Pierone'}>]>

In [3]: search.filter('term', first_name='Piero').count()                  
Out[3]: 0
```

My index contains only one entry with `first_name == 'Piero'` so I'd expect this to be returned and count equal to 1. I get 0 instead.

Comment: How do you insert data to your index ?

Comment: Ciao, are you sure that your first_name field is a keyword datatype? GET general-index/_mapping

Comment: Hello, I added using `es.index(index='general-index', id=1, body={first_name: 'Piero' ...})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this, it should work :

```
search.filter('term', first_name='piero').count()
```

The [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) lowercase all charachters, and it is not very useful to match exact queries. Refer to the warning section on the link to use match query instead, like this :

```
search.filter('match', first_name='Piero').count()
```

Here you have all the results with diferent queries and type of queries :

```
In [19]: search.filter('term', first_name='Piero').count()   
Out[19]: 0

In [20]: search.filter('term', first_name='piero').count()   
Out[20]: 1

In [21]: search.filter('match', first_name='Piero').count()   
Out[21]: 1

In [22]: search.filter('match', first_name='piero').count()   
Out[22]: 1
```

Comment: Correct, thank you! I read somewhere in the docs it would lowercase terms, what I naively assumed it would have been smart enoug to do it as well while filtering :) like this no term filter with uppercase letter will ever work